# Create JSON with dynamic using newtonsoft json.net

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net

I am trying to create or searealize json in this format

```
   {

     "title": "Star Wars",
    "link": "http://www.starwars.com",
    "description": "Star Wars blog.",
    "item": [
       {
         "title": "Episode VII",
         "description": "Episode VII production",
         "link": "episode-vii-production.aspx"
        },
        {
         "title": "Episode VITI",
         "description": "Episode VII production",
         "link": "episode-vii-production.aspx"
        }


        ]
       }
```

i am trying this achieve this

```
 dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();

o.title= "fdsfs";
o.link= "fsrg";
o.description="fdsfs";
      foreach (var adata in all)
                {
                o.item.title="fgfd";
                o.item.description="sample desc";
                o.item.link="http://google.com"
                } 
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
```

but than here it throws exception on foreach loop on item it tells it does not contain defination for the same etc .so what i am doing wrong and how to achieve the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `o.item` to assign values into it:

```
dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
var all = new object[] { new object() };

o.title= "fdsfs";
o.link= "fsrg";
o.description="fdsfs";
var items = new List<ExpandoObject>();
foreach (var adata in all)
{
    dynamic item = new ExpandoObject();
    item.title="fgfd";
    item.description="sample desc";
    item.link="http://google.com";
    items.Add(item);
} 
o.item = items;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
```

Comment: shouldn't `o.item` be a list?

Answer (score 2):

That is the construction you should have to get the json you've stated. The problem with your code is that item should be actually a list of items.

```
public class Item
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Item> item { get; set; }
}
```

Then you ca use this code:

```
 dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();

o.title= "fdsfs";
o.link= "fsrg";
o.description="fdsfs";
o.item = new List<ExpandoObject>();  
//although list of dynamics is not recommended as far as I remember
      foreach (var adata in all)
                {
                o.item.Add(new Item(){   
                title="fgfd",
                description="sample desc",
                link="http://google.com" });
                } 
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
```

Comment: i want achieve it dynamically  not using class, so is it possible ?

Comment: as long as you create a list of items (even if dynamicly), you're good to go

Comment: @FelixAv You add items  to  `o.item` without creating a list.

Comment: @Eser Thanks for the heads up